# Visual Studio installer Taskbar pin does not work after upgrade

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer

I am using the Windows installer project in Visual Studio 2017 to install a WPF application on client's machines.  The installer project is set up to automatically generate shortcuts to the application on both the desktop and the user's program menu.  One thing we have been notices that when the client installs an upgrade of the software, if they have pinned the application from the the program menu or the desktop the pinned icon will no longer work after the upgrade, even if the application is installed to the same application directory.
Is there anyway I can have the installer project set the shortcuts to work even after the application has been changed in some way but is still in the same location?

Comment: I haven't looked at this to be honest, but I know the primary cause is the use of major upgrades. This will remove the previous version's shortcuts and create new ones. Hence the pinning is affected (new identity for the shortcuts). I think Advanced Installer has some feature to deal with this, but I haven't looked into it. There are certainly some blogs that  describe shortcuts and pinning. [Alex Shevchuk's From MSI to WiX, Part 26 - Shortcut: To pin or not to pin?](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/archive/blogs/alexshev/from-msi-to-wix-part-26-shortcut-to-pin-or-not-to-pin).

Comment: The above link is from [Alex Shevchuk's blog series on MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/archive/blogs/alexshev/from-msi-to-wix).